# Limit of arc-length of a curve

Tags: analysis, continuity, arc-length

Let $L(f)$ denote the length of a curve $f$, if $f = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n$ then do we necessarily have that $L(f) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} L(f_n)$? I assume that we will have some continuity restrictions on $f, f_n$ but I'm not certain.

The curve I am particularly looking at is the Hilbert space-filling curve. Each iteration has length $2^n - \frac{1}{2^n}$, so can we definitely conclude from just this that the Hilbert curve itself has infinite length?

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_n f_n = f$? That is the crucial part...

Comment: That $f_n$ is a sequence of functions converging to $f$.

Comment: I understand that. But there are many different kinds of convergence. Back to my first comment...

Comment: For the sake of this question, say it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: What is uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 4):

We don't have equality (e.g. consider the graphs of $\sin(2^n x)/n$, $0 \le x \le 1$ approaching a straight line), but we do have
$L(f) \le \liminf L(f_n)$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample.